# How do you perform a bitwise operation using Querydsl in Spring using Hibernate with MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, querydsl

I have an int column in a mysql table which I am using for storing bits related to a status. I am interested in querying based on whether one or more bits are set in the status field.

I tried the following: `Expressions.booleanTemplate("(status & {0}) = 0", A_BIT_MASK);`
but, this gave me an `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '&'`.

I am using Spring Data with Hibernate and MySQL. I was trying to query DB using Querydsl.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create the bitwise in hibernate

```
public class MySQLDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect {

    public MySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("bitand", new SQLFunctionTemplate(IntegerType.INSTANCE, "(?1 & ?2)"));
    }
}
```

then you can reference this in either querydsl or hibernate

```
NumberTemplate<Integer> numberTemplate = Expressions.numberTemplate(Integer.class, "function('bitand', {0}, {1})", path, value);
```